# Elasticsearch is update API realtime?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

Is elasticsearch update realtime? I understand refresh interval is 1 second before updated document is available for search.

But, what if I update (increment a counter) a document several times within 1 second? Does each update request work on last updated document or last "Refreshed" document?

Answer (score 1):

It works on the last updated document. The refresh is only for making all the changes that happened since the last refresh available search.

Comment: l thanks.I am trying to  test this but I am running an error changing the refresh time config. Will update once I get test results...